# See process running over 30 minutes

Tags: command-line

I'm currently trying to find out how many of these processes have been running for more than 30 minutes

```
ps -ef | grep ffmpeg | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I would try something like

```
ps -eocomm=,etimes= | awk '$1 ~ /ffmpeg/ && $2 > 1800 {c++} END {print c}'
```